# How to convert ModX placeholder to PHP variable for use in xPDO query?

Tags: php, modx, modx-revolution

I want to use a placeholder from the Login plugin in an xPDO SQL query, eg:

```
$userid = [[+id]];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` = $userid";

$modx->query($sql);
```

However, if I echo the `$userid` var I just get `Array`.

Would anyone know the proper way of converting a ModX Placeholder into a PHP var?

Comment: I'm not familiar with modx, but what does `var_dump($userid);` give you?

Comment: @jeroen it just gives me NULL

Comment: Ummmmmm, I thought it was an array?

Comment: Sorry, syntax error on my behalf - I get: int(15) (15 being the number I am after)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MeltingDog,

$modx->toPlaceholder() is the only function which used $modx->getPlaceholder() and only serves to search a placeholder array created by $modx->toPlaceholder() and $modx->toPlaceholders() calls via PHP snippets and classes.

What you wanted to do is described in the [Login documentation](https://rtfm.modx.com/extras/revo/login/login.tutorials/login.using-pre-and-post-hooks) via the $hook variable.

The user is available via the means Login is used: 
$userObject = $hook->getValue('register.user');
or
$userObject = $hook->getValue('updateprofile.user');

In both cases the code would be completed thusly:

$userid = $user->getPrimaryKey();

or

$userid = $user->id;

or

$userid = $user->get('id');

Comment: There is a typo in $userid = $user=>get('id');

Should be  $userid = $user->get('id');

Answer (score 0):

I found it:

```
$userid = $modx->getPlaceholder('id');
```